# Connection String in Textbox

Tags: vb6, connection

I'am new in programming and my problem is. i have put my ado db connection string into a text box how can i call that text box? i'm creating my program in vb 6 and here's my code.

```
Private Sub lvButtons_H2_Click()
On Error GoTo errtrap
If Label47.Caption = "True" Then
MsgBox "INITIAL SETTING FOR SHIP ACCOUNT IS BEING PERFORMED", vbOKOnly, "ABORT"
Exit Sub
End If
Dim conas As New ADODB.Connection, rs01 As New ADODB.Recordset, rsx1 As New ADODB.Recordset, RS9 As New ADODB.Recordset
conas.Connectio`enter code here`nString = Text1155.Text
conas.Open
Set RS9 = New ADODB.Recordset
    RS9.ActiveConnection = conas
    RS9.CursorType = 3
    RS9.LockType = 3
    RS9.Open ("SELECT  * FROM [SHIPACCOUNT].[dbo].[SPARE PART LIST BOND 29 MONTHLY] WHERE NAMECODE = " & Text2.Text & "")
    Set DataReport2.DataSource = RS9

    DataReport2.Sections("Section2").Controls.item("LABEL12").Caption = Text1.Text
    DataReport2.Sections("Section2").Controls.item("LABEL11").Caption = Text3.Text

    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls.item("TEXT1").DataField = RS9![PARTSNAME].Name
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls.item("TEXT2").DataField = RS9![Price].Name
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls.item("TEXT3").DataField = RS9![unit].Name
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls.item("TEXT4").DataField = RS9![QTYAPPLY].Name
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls.item("TEXT5").DataField = RS9!QTYAPPROVE.Name
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls.item("TEXT6").DataField = RS9![AMOUNTAPPROVE].Name
    DataReport2.Sections("Section1").Controls.item("TEXT7").DataField = RS9![Date].Name


DataReport2.Show 1

Exit Sub
errtrap:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "The system encountered an error"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the connection string as parameter to the `Connection.Open method` 
Such as (assuming the name of the textbox is `Text1155`):

```
Dim conas As New ADODB.Connection

conas.Open Text1155.Text
```

(You don't need parenthesis for calling  a Sub in vb6)
Your code looks right otherwize...